# ¿Como encontrar el mayor y el menor elemento de un vector en Prolog?

Tags: prolog

es mi primera pregunta.
Resulta que tengo la especificación del problema, pero siguiéndola me arroja false.
cito: Sea V[1..n] un vector con elementos pueden ser comparados entre si. Suponiendo que n es una potencia de 2 mayor que 2, escribir las reglas y hechos que permitan encontrar el máximo y el mínimo de V[1..n] de acuerdo al siguiente seudo código.

```
funcion max−min(X[ 1 . . n ] : elem , c , f : nat) −> max, min: elem 
  si c == f entonces 
    <max, min> = <V[ c ] , V[ c]> 
  sino 
    m = (c + f ) div 2 
    <max1, min1> = max−min(V, c ,m) 
    <max2, min2> = max−min(V,m+1,f ) 
    max = maximo(max1, max2) 
    min = minimo(min1 , min2) 
  fin si 
fin funcion
```

Codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
maximo(X,Y,X):-X>=Y.
maximo(X,Y,Y):-X<Y.
minimo(X,Y,X):- X=<Y.
minimo(X,Y,Y):- X>Y.
maxmin([E1|[E2|_]],E1,E2,Maxi,Mini):- E1 == E2,(Maxi,Mini)=(E1,E2).
maxmin([E1|[E2|_]],E1,E2,Maxi,Mini):- M is (E1+E2) // 2,maxmin([E1|[E2|_]],E1,M,(Max,Min))
(Max1,Min1)=(Max,Min),maxmin([E1|[E2|_]],M+1,E2,(Max,Min)),
(Max2,Min2)=(Max,Min),Maxi=maximo(Max1,Max2),Mini=minimo(Min1,Min2).
```

La consola de comando de Prolog:

```
?- lista(L),maxmin(L,4,3,Maxi,Mini).
false
```

Comment: Yo pensé en algo similar a esto: 
maxmin(Lista,C,F,Min,Max):-
    length(Lista,N)
    , between(1,N,C)
    , between(1,N,F)
    , integer(C)
    , integer(F)
    , M is div((C+F),2)
    , maxmin(Lista,C,M,Max1,Min1)
    , maxmin(Lista,M+1,F,Max2,Min2)
    , maximo(Max1,Max2,Max)
    , minimo(Min1,Min2,Min).
maxmin(Lista,C,F, Min, Max):-
    C=:=F
    , nth0(C-1,Lista,Min)
    , nth0(C-1,Lista,Max).

Comment: Lo copie y pegue tal cual y queda en un bucle